# Is it possible to publish a large photo to facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is it possible using the javascript api to allow a user to post a large photo to their facebook wall? e.g. 500px x 500px, published like a user would normall upload a photo.

All I have been able to achieve so far is small thumbnails.

I currently have the following:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        "method": 'feed',
        "attachment":
        {
            "media": [{
                "type": "image",
                "src": "image.jpg",
                "href": "http://www.example.com/"
            }]
        }
    }, function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            //User posted
        } else {
            //User didn't post
        }
      }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're posting to the user's feed connection (i.e a wall post) with an image attached - you should use the API to post to their photos directly to upload a photo (see the [Graph API Poto documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos))

[edited because this was 'too vague']

You are posting a 'Post' with an image attached, the image in that case is an attachment to the post, it's not rendered in a large size on Facebook.com.

What you probably should be doing is uploading a photo to the user's 'photos' connection like the documentation i linked. There's also a how-to here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea. If someone is "sharing" a photo, why would you want it uploaded to the users photo album?

Comment: This is how it works on facebook.com, photos shared directly to a user's timeline are put into the 'timeline photos' album